# Select amount for given year

Tags: mysql

I have a table with countries, years and amounts for each year. I'm trying to write a query that will sum the total amounts for a given year and give it to me as a column.

For example, to have an output that looks like:

```
Country   1991     1992     1993
France     25       12       38
```

I tried a query like this, but to no avail:

```
SELECT 
     country as "Recipient", 
     SUM(usd_amount) AS "1991" WHEN project_year = 1991,
     SUM(usd_amount) AS "1992" WHEN project_year = 1992,
     SUM(usd_amount) AS "1993" WHEN project_year = 1993

FROM tb1

GROUP BY project_year, country
order by country, project_year
```

Any Suggestions?
Thanks!
Chris

Comment: share the exapmle of data stored in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT 
     country as "Recipient", 
     SUM(if(project_year = 1991, usd_amount, 0)) AS "1991",
     SUM(if(project_year = 1992, usd_amount, 0)) AS "1992",
     SUM(if(project_year = 1993, usd_amount, 0)) AS "1993",
FROM tb1
GROUP BY country
ORDER BY country
```

PS: It makes no sense to order by project year as you're already aggregating on it.

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
SELECT 
     country as "Recipient", 
     SUM(case WHEN project_year = 1991 then usd_amount else 0 end) AS "1991" ,
     SUM(case WHEN project_year = 1992 then usd_amount else 0 end) AS "1992" ,
     SUM(case WHEN project_year = 1993 then usd_amount else 0 end) AS "1993" 

FROM tb1

GROUP BY country, project_year
order by country, project_year
```